# Symfony2 Routing within a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, directory-structure

I have a symfony project where i have seperated my code into two different bundles lets say HomeBundle and AppBundle however the routes are commonly accessible inside both bundle.

eg:- `/home` defined in HomeBundle can also be accessed from `AppBundle`

and

`/App` defined in AppBundle can also be accessed from `HomeBundle`

what i want is to access `/home` ONLY from `HomeBundle` and `/App` from Only `AppBundle` I'm looking for 'structuring' my code in a way where i dont have to write any logic to accomplish this, but instead leverage symfony frameworks structure to do this for me, something along the lines of restricting routing to only within the bundle, or some way where the route definition goes 'out of scope' when inside the wrong bundle

im using annotaions for routing, and defined in app/config/routing.yml

edit: the application requires subomain partitions so i'm also using [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html#using-placeholders) host/default with placeholder

any help would be appreciated :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't going to be possible, primarily because of the architecture of Symfony bundles. While separating your code into bundles is good from a cognitive point of view, Symfony doesn't have the concept of being "in" a bundle; what code is run (specifically your controller actions) is usually handled by routes, and routes have to be compiled together from ALL bundles to ensure that a request can be routed successfully.

You would have to write extra code to accomplish what you're asking - my initial thought would be your own `Controller` class (maybe extending from `FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`) that ran some code before a request (see [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) that may achieve this).

Fundamentally this is an architectural decision for you and my question would be - why do you not want to be able to access `/home` from the `AppBundle`? Would a security / role set up work as well or are you trying to sandbox code?

**EDIT** After some further detail, it turns out that the requirement is for two different actions for the same URL path (e.g. `/home`) but on different domains e.g. `www.example.com/home` and `subdomain.example.com/home`. In this instance it wasn't about code sharing but URLs so Symfony's [host/domain based routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html) solution worked.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer! i'm doing this because i have someting like ' www.example.com ' which is the product's home page (resides in HomeBundle) where you can register for our web service and we also have ' subdomain.example.com ' (resides in AppBundle) which is the actual web service that the client registered for. the current setup allows a person to access "subdomain.example.com/home" which should not be the case. only "example.com/home" should be allowed

Comment: as a last resort i could use route prefix option in the routing.yml to get what i want (almost) :P

Comment: When is a user "allowed" to access subdomain.example.com/access? You can provide a domain/host parameter for routing ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html)) or if there are more security concerns maybe look into [security voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html)?

Comment: hey it worked with the 'domain/host parameter for routing' bit, thanks to you, i took a second look at it and it clicked. later on i will be posting the Detailed correct answer here myself, you may want to edit your answer to include that snippet, because we need an accepted answer after all ;)

Comment: I've popped details into an edit section above, glad it worked and got to the root of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I was under the assumption that business logic inside bundles are isolated and would not be 'aware' of routes defined inside other bundles, turns out the routes are globally available to all bundles, i wanted to use the framework of symfony to achieve what i asked for, it happens so there is no way to do it. i probably should use Listeners or before filters etc to achieve this. John Noel answered this.

Luckily for me, the bundles happen to operate on separate Domains (one on the main domain and the other on the subdomain) i noticed this after a chat with @John Noel he suggested matching the Route Based on the Host/Domain. i had this in place previously, upon a second look i figured out i have to -based on the domain redirect all (except for a white list of routes) routes to a controller that throws a 404 exception. Here is what i mean.

```
Home_restrict:
    path:     /{slug}
    host:     "{domain}"
    defaults:
        _controller: HomeBundle:Home:notfound
    requirements:
       domain: example.com|www.example.com
       slug: ^(?!.*(admin|login)$).*
```

Routes that appear on top of the list on the page takes precedence, so this should be placed appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `routing.yml` per bundle, and include these in your "global" routing:

```
# src/HomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
home:
    resource: "@HomeBundle/Controller/HomeController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

and

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
home:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/AppController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

then import them in `app/config/routing.yml`, and maybe even prefix it over there?

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /app
```